# How to validate column text?

Tags: custom-list, validation

I have a custom list, in a column the users must enter a month from a drop-down menu(January, February, ... ), but when they use datasheet view to register the month manual I get different text formats (JANUARY, January and january), is there any way to restrict users from register only this type(January). I cant disable datasheet view

Comment: What's the SharePoint version, I tried this with choice field and quick view that working properly at SharePoint 2013

Comment: Is the Enter your own choice enabled on the choice column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropdown field should not allow users to enter different values:

- If it is small/big casing issue, it should adjust automatically:
  [image]

[image]

- If the user trie to fill the field, it should show him dropdown (even in datasheet view):
  [image]
- And if the user enters an incorrect value by the ingenuity of copy-paste, then it should show him an error and not allow to save changes with wrong input:
  [image]